# univariate linear regression tests for feature selection?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have been reading about the f_regression function that is available under the package feature_selection of scikit. According to what I read and I cite it says:

> Linear model for testing the individual effect of each of many
>   regressors. This is a scoring function to be used in a feature
>   seletion procedure, not a free standing feature selection procedure.
>
> This is done in 2 steps:
>
> - The correlation between each regressor and the target is computed,
>     that is, ((X[:, i] - mean(X[:, i])) * (y - mean_y)) / (std(X[:, i]) *
>     std(y)).
> - It is converted to an F score then to a p-value.

So in the first part I suppose that they are calculating the correlation coefficients, but I cannot find how to do the part of converting from those correlation coefficients to F score and then to p-values. Could anybody would put some analytical example to know how to do that process?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If we use [this example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/feature_selection/plot_f_test_vs_mi.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-feature-selection-plot-f-test-vs-mi-py):

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.feature_selection import f_regression
from scipy import stats

np.random.seed(0)
X = np.random.rand(1000, 3)
y = X[:, 0] + np.sin(6 * np.pi * X[:, 1]) + 0.1 * np.random.randn(1000)
```

y = x<sub>1</sub> + sin(6 * pi * x<sub>2</sub>) + 0.1 * N(0, 1), that is the third feature is completely irrelevant.

```py
f_test, p_values = f_regression(X, y)
f_test_norm = f_test/np.max(f_test)

plt.figure(figsize=(25, 5))
for i in range(3):
    plt.subplot(1, 3, i + 1)
    plt.scatter(X[:, i], y, edgecolor='black', s=20)
    plt.xlabel("$x_{}$".format(i + 1), fontsize=14)
    if i == 0:
        plt.ylabel("$y$", fontsize=14)
    plt.title("Normalized F-test={:.2f},F-test={:.2f}, p-value={:.2f}".format(f_test_norm[i],f_test[i],p_values[i]),
              fontsize=16)
plt.show()
```

[image]

The values for F-test and p-value are as follows:

```py
>>> f_test, p_values
(array([187.42118421,  52.52357392,   0.47268298]),
 array([3.19286906e-39, 8.50243215e-13, 4.91915197e-01]))
```

Let's first compute correlation:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(X)
df['y'] = y
            0         1         2         y
0    0.548814  0.715189  0.602763  1.004714
1    0.544883  0.423655  0.645894  0.900226
2    0.437587  0.891773  0.963663 -0.919160
...

>>> df.corr()['y']
0    0.397624
1   -0.223601
2    0.021758
y    1.000000

corr = df.corr()['y'][:3]
```

Then, according to [this](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/f0ab589f/sklearn/feature_selection/univariate_selection.py#L302), they calculate `degrees_of_freedom`, as `len(y) - 2` if `center` parameter is true and `len(y) - 1` otherwise:

```py
degrees_of_freedom = y.size - (2 if center else 1)
```

F-statistic is calculated as

`F = corr ** 2 / (1 - corr ** 2) * degrees_of_freedom`
which in our case gives:

```py
0    187.421184
1     52.523574
2      0.472683
Name: y, dtype: float64
```

p-values are then calculated using [survival function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.f.html):

```py
pv = stats.f.sf(F, 1, degrees_of_freedom)
>>> pv
array([3.19286906e-39, 8.50243215e-13, 4.91915197e-01])
```